# php/codeigniter - using while to link two functions

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've got some follow/unfollow and block/unblock functions in my app. They work fine and the correct data is populating my database. Here's an outline of my logic:

```
if($this->user_is_followed) {
    //show unfollow button
}else {     
    //show follow button

}

if($this->user_is_blocked) {    
    //show unblock button
}else {
    //show block button
}
```

One issue: I need to link the follow/unfollow and block/unblock functions for these 2 scenarios:

1 - If a user is following someone, and clicks the block button, that user should be blocked and unfollowed (right now, the user is blocked, but not unfollowed)

2 - If a user is blocking someone, and clicks the follow button, that user should be followed and unblocked (right now, the user is followed, but not unblocked)

I tried using -while- to link the 2 functions, but nothing shows up, not even errors, just a blank screen:

Here's my attempt at the while logic:

```
    if($this->user_is_followed) {
        while($this->user_is_blocked) {
            //show unfollow button
        }
    }       
    else if($this->user_is_blocked) {
        while($this->user_is_followed) {        
        //show follow button 
        }       
    }
```

Simply put, I'm trying to figure out which php control structure I can use for this. Is it -while- or something else?

Comment: good lord no!  while($this->user_is_blocked) will never complete like this since its going to be a set value. see the while manual: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

Comment: This `while` doesn't have all the meanings of english `while`.

Comment: @KaiQing - I'm already reading through it, thanks. Just figured I'd ask to see if anyone knew which one to use offhand.

Comment: @itachi - Yes, I realized that after getting the blank screen. I'm still reading to see what might work and decided to ask in case someone knew which control structure to use.

Comment: Your logic is flawed for a social network anyway and that seems to be the idea behind what you're doing. If I have a user blocked the only place I want to see them is on my blocked list, I don't want to see anything they have to do or say or a follow button for them. That is the whole point of blocking. It makes sense to unfollow someone and block them but not vice versa. The only time you'd need an unblock would be on a blocked users list.

Comment: @rick - that might be so but the question is whether or not either of these would work for his needs, not necessarily if we think his idea is a sane one

Comment: @RickCalder - Actually, the logic is not flawed. If a user decides to visit the profile page of another user that they have blocked (for whatever reason), they need to have the option to unblock that user. Online relationships go back-and-forth just like real life ones. This is already being done on Twitter, so it's hardly novel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one would be fine depending on whether or not you could be followed and blocked at the same time.

Since it looks like you're doing this for inline output, you might want to just condense it down to a ternary:

```
<?php echo ($this->user_is_followed ? 'unfollow button' : 'follow button'); ?>
```

The ternary would be bad if you had extensive markup since echoing html in php is generally a dumb idea. But if you were using a library like jquery and listeners on classes you could assign a "followed" or "not-followed" class on an `<a>` tag, then display according to css... hope that made sense.

Comment: You have hit on the main issue. I don't want users to be followed and blocked at the same time. I'm going to try your suggestion and will be back shortly. Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your previous outline of logic.

```
if($this->user_is_followed {
    //show unfollow button
}
else {      
    //show follow button
}
if($this->user_is_blocked) {    
    //show unblock button
}
else {
    //show block button
}
```

the only changes that will happen is the control of your follow,unfollow,block and unblock buttons. because there is no action that needs to take place in displaying the buttons right? so those 2 scenarios should take place after the button is clicked not when the button is displayed. I suggest create the functions for your follow,unfollo,block, and unblock buttons base on the scenario you want to happen.